# MySQL Select with regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table in MySQL, TAB_FILE with below columns (file_pattern contains regular expressions correspoding to file names) -

```
client_id | file_pattern
------------------------
91 | ^s101-XXX-typeA_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.csv.gz$
92 | ^s102-YYY-typeA_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.csv.gz$
```

And I have a list of files containing file names, for e.g.,

```
file_names.txt - 
s101-XXX-typeA_2015-10-12.csv.gz
s102-YYY-typeA_2015-10-10.csv.gz
```

I want to write a query to find the client_id for each file name in file_names.txt

```
cat file_names.txt | while read line
do
  mysql -u*** -p*** DB1 -e "select client_id from TAB_FILE where $line rlike file_pattern"
done
```

This SQL Query is not working. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's not working about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports POSIX-style regular expressions, but not the Perl-compatible ones.
In your example, you'll have to use `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d` to make it work.

Comment: So is there any way we can convert this RegEx to POSIX-style RegEx in the select query itself ?

Comment: I doubt there's a proper way of doing that since PCREs have features not available in POSIX regular expressions. Manually converting a subset of those features is error-prone too (e.g. replacing `\d` by `[[:digit:]]` might work in your examples, but `[\d\w]` will not). Alternatively [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme) seems to allow you to use PCREs in MySQL, but I've never tested it, so I've no idea how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your "$line" parameter into quotes, something like:

```
"select client_id from TAB_FILE where '$line' rlike file_pattern"
```

Then it will work.

Comment: I don't get any error message, just that it does not return any result when it should.